# page get refresh evenif usercontrol validation is false

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, custom-validators

I have usercontrol in which I have written Custom-validation which checks whether the entered data in textbox is correct Location or not.On button click click I have checked (page.IsValid) bit,

Even-if validation fails it reload the entire page in which the usercontrol is added

the Custom validation look like;

```
   <asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1"  runat="server" Width="102px" Style="margin-left:37px !important" OnServerValidate="TextValidate" ControlToValidate="txtLocationId" ErrorMessage="Incorrect Location.">
  </asp:CustomValidator>
```

In UserControl.aspx.cs :->

```
protected void TextValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            string value = string.Empty;
            dbconfig.conDatabase2.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdsqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmdsqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            string locID = args.Value.ToString();
            cmdsqlcmd.CommandText = "";
            cmdsqlcmd.Connection = dbconfig.conDatabase2;

            Object ob = cmdsqlcmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (ob == null)
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
            else
            {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
        }
```

On button Click:

protected void goButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
Code goes here...
             }
        }

In aspx Page:

```
<%@ Register Src="UserControl/UserControlFilter.ascx" TagName="UserControlFilter"
    TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <AjaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </AjaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="300000">
    </asp:Timer>

   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                        </Triggers>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                          <div class="locadetail" id="bigtrends" style="border-radius:5px;width: 884px; z-index: 100; border-width: 1px;
                                margin: 10px; height: 398px !important; float: left; background-color: #fff !important;">
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly let me know if I m going wrong somewhere

thanks

Comment: your code will help to answer others. `onclick="yourfunctionName();return false;"` it will help

Comment: Please provide your code. I can't tell that you're using server side or client side validation

Answer (score 1):

Custom validation have two modes 1. Client Side and 2. Server Side. If your using only server side validation then the page will post back without any check. And before Page Validation event, Page load is fired so add client validation function. which will validate your test. If data is which need to check is only available on server only then use Web service to validate.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> function TextValidate(oSrc, args){ // validation logic
```

}

`<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1"  runat="server" Width="102px" Style="margin-left:37px !important" OnServerValidate="TextValidate" ControlToValidate="txtLocationId" ErrorMessage="Incorrect Location." ClientValidationFunction="TextValidate" >
  </asp:CustomValidator>`

Answer (score 0):

Your call simply (seems to me) calls the server for validation. So to avoid reloading of the page, you can perform a `JavaScript` validation *first* and after server side validation *too*.

```
$("#button").click(function(e) {
     var valueToValidate = $("#button").val(); 

     .... VALIDATION 

     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Something like this *should* do a stuff. But better then yo provide more code, for more suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your serverside validation (TextValidate) you need to set `arguments.IsValid` as false in case of validation fail